# Fore a file to only open in adobe acrobat

Tags: windows, pdf, scripting, adobe

I have a pdf that needs to only be opened using acrobat. This is easy enough on a configured computer. But is there a way to only allow this file to be opened using adobe regardless of what the default program is. I have a lot of computers in my firm and I have to configure app defaults for every user. If I could just force the file to require acrobat that would be awesome.

Comment: Ask on "Super User"

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to indicate that a PDF should only be opened with a particular PDF viewing application. You would not even be able to rely on JavaScript in the PDF to put up a dialog to let the user know they should view the document in Adobe Acrobat because not all PDF viewers implement JavaScript.

The closest thing I can think of would be to use a rights management tool that only Adobe Acrobat works with, even this though is not guaranteed to stop users from trying to open a PDF with a viewer other than the one you want them to view it with.

PDF's goal/purpose is to provide a file format the allows the author to share content across platforms without noticeable differences. What you are looking to do is something PDF was not truly designed for.